# can vscode extension prettier do the string padding?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I want the following effect for the import path. Can prettier do it?

```
import a                from "a"
import bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb from "b"
import c                from "c"
```

Comment: prettier no, but look at various `Align` extensions.  For example, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matthewthorning.align-vertically

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. The default formatting for import statements is different from what you're seeking and it is not configurable.